# Deleting items based on another list column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have two list 
1. Resgined Employee IDs
2. Employee details (It has Employee ID)
Is ther any way I can compare the column and delete resigned ps numbers records from Employee details list.

Is it possible without using code/programming?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add column from Resigned Employee Id as a lookup column to Employee details.
Then you can filter all records that have this column not empty and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a workflow, running on the 1 list, have it trigger on item change (for example if position changed to resigned) to delete the item with lookupId equivalent to current items id.